# Do allergens have structural similarities to pathogens?

Tags: immune-system, allergies, antigen

The conventional popular explanation of allergies is that the immune system confuses allergens with pathogens and reacts to them as such.  Is there any merit to this explanation?  If so, I would expect it to be possible to predict which proteins would be allergens by their structural similarity to pathogens.  Is it?  If not, how else could we explain which proteins are allergens and which aren't?

Comment: Have you done any basic research?The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allergen) article is a good read to start with. I think you should go through this to finf out [What should you do before you ask the question?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: Allergens **are** antigens. Please do some research on what each term refers to. Wikipedia is an excellent resource.

Comment: @MattDMo Sorry, I think I meant "pathogen" instead of "antigen".  I will change my question.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh You seem to have linked to the page on homework questions.  This is not a homework question.  Is this the page that you meant to link to?  And I have done research to try to answer this question myself.

Comment: Low effort questions are closed under the tag '**homework question**' and I meant to link it to the '**What should I do before I ask the question?** ' paragraph. You have to share your research (mentioned in a paragraph below it).

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh no, not all low-effort questions are to be closed as homework. See the recent discussions on meta. Homework is for homework, low-effort can be closed as too broad, unclear, or using a custom close reason.